# debounce function won't fire in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been having trouble getting a debounce function to fire in a watch function in vue 3 with composition API. I had it working in the options API. The watch function is working (just not the debounce function inside of the watcher).

```js
setup() {
  const handleDebounce = (fn, delay) => {
    console.log('test') // this works
    var timeoutID = null
    return function () {
      console.log('test') // this does not work
      clearTimeout(timeoutID)
      var args = arguments
      var that = this
      timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
        fn.apply(that, args)
      }, delay)
    }
  }

  watch(
    () => watched.value,
    input => {
      //doesn't work
      handleDebounce(function (t) {
        console.log(t)
      }, 3000)
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either write the watch like this:

```js
watch(
  () => watched.value,
  handleDebounce(function (input) {
    console.log(input)
  }, 3000)
)
```

Or create a debounced function outside of the watch and then call it within the watch.

```js
const someLogging = handleDebounce(function (t) {
  console.log(t)
}, 3000)

watch(
  () => watched.value,
  input => {
    someLogging(input)
  }
)
```

Comment: I thought I had it structured as the second, but I switched to the first and it worked. Appreciate your knowledge and time!

Comment: Quick note, both modes above work.

Comment: How would I pass a delay variable into handleDebounce() from the watcher?